# I want to print a tabulated list using tabulate, but gives me error

Tags: python, tabulate

```
list02 = [[101, 75.00, 69.31, 19, 'FAR'],
          [102, 75.00, 68.71, 19, 'FAR'],
          [103, 75.00, 67.55, 18, 'MIA'],
          [104, 75.00, 65.41, 18, 'FSD'],
          [105, 74.00, 64.39, 18, 'FAR'],
          [106, 73.00, 63.36, 17, 'CLT']]

from tabulate import tabulate

print(tabulate(list02, headers=["Line#", "Credit", "Hrs", "Days Off", "ARP"]))
```

ERROR IS FIXED!

But now asking to have the right column be tabulated on right hand side just like the values.

---

```
Line#    Credit    Hrs          Days Off  Overnight
-------  --------  ---------  ----------  -----------
    101        75      69.31          19  FAR
    102        75      68.71          19  FAR
    103        75      67.55          18  MIA
    104        75      65.41          18  FSD
    105        74      64.39          18  FAR
    106        73      63.36          17  CLT
```

Using Python 3.8 running on Spyder IDE

Thank you in advance for the help!
**recently edited  --> new question!

Comment: You miss a comma between each sublist

Comment: Since you edited your answer with commas. I am sure you won't have any issues now

Comment: Thank you!!! Yes fixed it, and had to install tabulate with: conda install -c conda-forge tabulate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list02 = [[101, 75.00, 69.31, 19, 'FAR'],
          [102, 75.00, 68.71, 19, 'FAR'],
          [103, 75.00, 67.55, 18, 'MIA'],
          [104, 75.00, 65.41, 18, 'FSD'],
          [105, 74.00, 64.39, 18, 'FAR'],
          [106, 73.00, 63.36, 17, 'CLT']]

from tabulate import tabulate

print(tabulate(list02, headers=["Line#", "Credit", "Hrs", "Days Off", "ARP"]))
```

Comment: Thank you for the time to answer! I had to actually install tabulate by: conda install -c conda-forge tabulate